How to appendBuffer event.data received through websocket from MediaSource in Safari
I am currently creating a simple page that takes data received through a web socket and distributes it to the web page as HTML. In other than Safari browsers, appendBuffer works well to distribute event.data received through websocket from MediaSource to the page, but I read that Safari does not support MediaSource. So, is there a way to receive websocket data as is and display it on the screen without using hls? My source is below.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Video Stream Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col">
        <video class="video-background" id="livestream" style="width:1500px; transform:rotate(180deg);" autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        startPlay();
    });

    let mseQueue = [],
        mseSourceBuffer, mseStreamingStarted = false, videoSound = false;

    var ws;
    const wsUrl = `{websocket url}`;

    function startPlay() {
        const browser = getBrowser();
        if (browser === 'Safari') {
            // Sources to be added in Safari
        } else {
            openws(true);
        }
        
    }

    function openws(start) {
        const mse = new MediaSource();
        const livestream = document.getElementById('livestream');
        livestream.src = URL.createObjectURL(mse);

        mse.addEventListener('sourceopen', function() {
            ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
            ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

            ws.onopen = function() {
                console.log('Connected to WebSocket');
            };

            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                const data = new Uint8Array(event.data);
                if (data[0] === 9) {
                    const decodedArr = data.slice(1);
                    const mimeCodec = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(decodedArr);

                    if (mimeCodec.indexOf(',') > 0) {
                        videoSound = true;
                    }
                    console.log('second packet with codec data: ' + mimeCodec);
                    mseSourceBuffer = mse.addSourceBuffer(`video/mp4; codecs="${mimeCodec}"`);
                    mseSourceBuffer.mode = "segments";
                    mseSourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", pushPacket);
                } else {
                    readPacket(event.data);
                }
            };

            ws.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log('WebSocket error '+event.data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    openws(false);
                }, 1000);
            };

            ws.onclose = function (event) {
                console.log('WebSocket reconnection opened');
                console.log(event.code);

                if (!event.wasClean) {
                    console.log('WebSocket not was clean close..');
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    openws(false);
                }, 10000);
            };
        });
    }

    function pushPacket() {
        if (!mseSourceBuffer.updating) {
            if (mseQueue.length > 0) {
                const packet = mseQueue.shift();
                mseSourceBuffer.appendBuffer(packet);
                mseSourceBuffer.remove(packet);
            } else {
                mseStreamingStarted = false;
            }
        }
        
       
        const livestream = document.getElementById('livestream');

        if (livestream.buffered.length > 0) {
            if (document.hidden && !videoSound) {
                livestream.currentTime = livestream.buffered.end(livestream.buffered.length - 1) - 0.5;
            }
        }
    }

    function readPacket(packet) {
        if (!mseStreamingStarted) {
            mseSourceBuffer.appendBuffer(packet);
            mseStreamingStarted = true;
            return;
        }

        mseQueue.push(packet);

        if (!mseSourceBuffer.updating) {
            pushPacket();
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('livestream').addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
        const livestream = document.getElementById('livestream');
        livestream.play();
    });

    document.getElementById('livestream').addEventListener('pause', () => {
        const livestream = document.getElementById('livestream');
        if (livestream.currentTime > livestream.buffered.end(livestream.buffered.length - 1)) {
            livestream.currentTime = livestream.buffered.end(livestream.buffered.length - 1) - 0.1;
            livestream.play();
        }
    });

    function getBrowser() {
        const ua = navigator.userAgent;

        if (/^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(ua)) {
            return 'Safari';
        }

        if (/chrome|crios/i.test(ua) && !/edge|edg|opr|opera|brave/i.test(ua)) {
            return 'Chrome';
        }

        return 'Other';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>


If you see anything strange in the source, please let me know. We plan to create a web page that will run not only on Safari, but also on iOS, Mac, and Windows.

Without HLS"? Can you use a server-side language like PHP? You need a PHP script that gets or receives the socket data and sends it out (to whatever called the script, for example the video tag).
